# PHP long running script with ignore_user_abort(true), allow user to continue browsing

Tags: php

I have a php script that goes something like this:

```php
ob_end_clean();
header("Connection: close\r\n");
header("Content-Encoding: none\r\n");
ignore_user_abort(true); // optional
set_time_limit(1*3600); // 1 hora max
ob_start();

$filepath = DOL_DOCUMENT_ROOT . '/exports/export-' . date('Ymd-his');
if (!file_exists($filepath)) {
    mkdir($filepath, 0777, true);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO export_process(folder,fk_user) VALUES ('" . $filepath . "', {$user->id});";
$resSql = $db->query($sql);
if (!$resSql) {
    http_response_code(500); // Internal Server Error
    echo json_encode(['error' => $db->lasterror()]);
    $size = ob_get_length();
    header("Content-Length: $size");
    ob_end_flush();     // Strange behaviour, will not work
    flush();            // Unless both are called !
    ob_end_clean();
    exit();
}

echo json_encode(['success' => true]);
$size = ob_get_length();
header("Content-Length: $size");
ob_end_flush();     // Strange behaviour, will not work
flush();            // Unless both are called !
ob_end_clean();

// Here goes the long running export function
// Every completed step updates the inserted export_process to increase the completion percentage
```

This script is called via ajax, I want the user to be able to call the script and then continue navigating the website, then if he visits the same page he will see a progress bar.

Everything works fine, the script returns inmediately to the ajax call and I reload the page, however the page never loads, as if it's waiting for the long running function to finish.

I thought `ignore_user_abort(true)` was supposed to help with this, is that not the case?

- I'm using PHP Version 7.4.30.
- Local development is Windows 11, XAMPP
- Server is Windows Server 2022, Apache

Comment: Are you using (the default) session handler?

Comment: Should be, I don't remeber changing snything about it in php config.

Comment: The default session handler in PHP uses files, this will create a filelock, meaning the next request won't be able to load untill the lock is resolved. You should close the session to resolve the issue (or use a different session handler)

Comment: I think so? Right before the long running script I call `session_write_close();` and then the user should be able to browse again. Since my script just reads data from database and creates files it shouldn't need to write anything to session after it's started.

Comment: That is correct yes