# How to have a long-running PHP script triggered by a request without blocking subsequent requests

Tags: php

I have a php script that goes something like this:

```php
// filename = htdocs/api/generateFiles.php

ob_end_clean();
header("Connection: close\r\n");
header("Content-Encoding: none\r\n");
ignore_user_abort(true); // optional
set_time_limit(1*3600); // 1 hora max
ob_start();

$filepath = DOL_DOCUMENT_ROOT . '/exports/export-' . date('Ymd-his');
if (!file_exists($filepath)) {
    mkdir($filepath, 0777, true);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO export_process(folder,fk_user) VALUES ('" . $filepath . "', {$user->id});";
$resSql = $db->query($sql);
if (!$resSql) {
    http_response_code(500); // Internal Server Error
    echo json_encode(['error' => $db->lasterror()]);
    $size = ob_get_length();
    header("Content-Length: $size");
    ob_end_flush();     // Strange behaviour, will not work
    flush();            // Unless both are called !
    ob_end_clean();
    exit();
}

echo json_encode(['success' => true]);
$size = ob_get_length();
header("Content-Length: $size");
ob_end_flush();     // Strange behaviour, will not work
flush();            // Unless both are called !
ob_end_clean();


session_write_close();
// Here goes the long running export function
// Every completed step updates the inserted export_process to increase the completion percentage
```

I have 3 environments.

Local, running on Windows 11, XAMPP

Testing and Production running both on a QNAP NAS, Linux.

- On local when I call `htdocs/api/generateFiles.php` via AJAX I inmediately can browse the website while the script runs.
- On Testing when I call `htdocs/api/generateFiles.php` via AJAX I get the loading animation and doesn't end until the script ends, then the page reloads and I see the finished output.
- On Production when I call `htdocs/api/generateFiles.php` via AJAX the page reloads almost instantly and in the logs I can see that at some point my script stops running (I've added `error_log` on a loop while building an array and out of 50 steps, thr last print is `step 33` then the next line log is `-- END access to htdocs/api/generateFiles.php`)

I don't even know why the difference between testing and production because it's the same environment, same php configuration and same .htaccess.

For some reason `ignore_user_abort(true)` doesn't work on the QNAP, I have `output_buffering = 4096` which is how I fixed this not working on my local environment.

What else could be wrong?

---

Edit:

@acran I'm not sure what else to add to the explanation, as I said I call a script via AJAX then I want the user to be able to keep browsing the page, on my last question DarkBee explained that the ajax request, even though it had `ignore_user_abort` set to true, had a filelock and the user couldn't browse because of this, which was fixed with `session_write_close` right before the long running function. As I explain on this question, on local everything works. Then I encounter 2 different non-working scenarios on testing and production (same machine) and I'm trying to figure out why.

Since the AJAX part seems to be confusing you we can take it out, imagine instead of an ajax call I visit `htdocs/api/generateFiles.php` manually to run the script, then close the browser tab, since we have `ignore_user_abort(true)` the script should continue running even though I closed the tab, now I open another tab on the sabe website, on local I can browse and check the script's progress on a different page, on testing and production this new tab would stay loading until the script finsihed, then the user would be able to browse the site.

Comment: There was a discussion about the same issue in a previous question from the OP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76818318/php-long-running-script-with-ignore-user-aborttrue-allow-user-to-continue-bro (I share this so that users don't ask the same questions in the comment section)

Comment: Sorry, @Daviid, but your question as well as the [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76818318/php-long-running-script-with-ignore-user-aborttrue-allow-user-to-continue-bro) lack most critical infos to enable us to help you. It is not clear at all, what you're trying to achieve, what you tried, what's not working as expected... also, when you "_call it via AJAX_" this should work completely in the background, so no navigation to a new site, no reloading and no loading animation. Without knowing your AJAX code we can not reproduce any of this^^

Comment: @acran updated main post with an explanation, what do you not understand?

Comment: Please be warned that your `INSERT` query is highly vulnerable for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Comment: That particular case is not vulnerable as there's no values a user can manipulate. As for others, there's nothing I can do, Dolibarr does not support prepared statements. Old codebase problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I'm understanding this correctly, what you want to achieve is to have a long-running PHP script, triggered by a web request (in your case by an AJAX request), while the server still continues to serve other PHP pages so the user can navigate your sites while the first script is still running in the background?

Then there seem to be two separate problems here:

> - On Testing when I call `htdocs/api/generateFiles.php` via AJAX I get the loading animation and doesn't end until the script ends, then the page reloads and I see the finished output.

I.e., after triggering your long-running script `htdocs/api/generateFiles.php` trying to navigate to other pages will block until the script finishes?

This actually implicates that `ignore_user_abort(true)` is working exactly as expected since your script continues running in the background.

That new requests are blocking until the script finishes is most probably caused by the limit of parallel requests your web server is configured to handle. How to adjust this configuration depends on your web server:

- for `apache` have a look at [`MaxRequestWorkers`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mpm_common.html#maxrequestworkers) for example
- for the [PHP built-in web server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) increase `PHP_CLI_SERVER_WORKERS`

Another resource that could be blocking your requests is the database: if your script is accessing the database - especially writing - this could lock the affected tables/databases for other database clients.

To test for this situation add logging before/after database requests in the code; write a test script that doesn't access the database - instead of the long-running one or one as a simple test page while the background task is still running.

> - On Production when I call `htdocs/api/generateFiles.php` via AJAX the page reloads almost instantly and in the logs I can see that at some point my script stops running (I've added `error_log` on a loop while building an array and out of 50 steps, thr last print is `step 33` then the next line log is `-- END access to htdocs/api/generateFiles.php`)

Without seeing the actual code we can only speculate here. It seems the script dies unexpectedly. This can be caused by system limits, e.g., [`max_execution_time`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) - which you already increased - or the [`memory_limit`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit), or by some exception in your code...

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into all of that. Production stopped failing for some reason, all I did was change the order of the `error_log` statement to see if the line right after was failing and `step 33` disappeared but no, it just didn't fail at all :/